# Как вам идея перенести баннер stack overflow под ответы?

Tags: предложение, дизайн, реклама

Подсказка "задать вопрос на Stack Overflow", разделяющая заголовок и тело вопроса - выглядит не очень хорошо.

Рассмотрим на живом примере:
[image: С баннером]

[image: Без баннера]

Конечно, это лично моё мнение, но, может кому-нибудь тоже понравится моя идея:
перенести баннер под ответы. (Ознакомился с вопросом, ответами, не нашёл нужного ответа - задал свой вопрос.)

Comment: Зачем вообще этот баннер, если я уже на SO =/

Comment: @Suvitruf было бы не прилично попросить удалить свою рекламу со своего сайта, по-этому я максимально корректно предложил, но, да, ваше предложение тоже подходит)

Comment: Я понимаю, если бы я зашёл на en SO, а там бы была реклама ru SO, т.к. у меня IP Российский. Но на ru SO в этом банере нет смысла вообще.

Comment: А у меня нету такого

Comment: @Grundy, разумеется нету, славная баннерорезка делает своё дело.

Comment: У меня баннерорезка отключена тут, но всё равно нету. Видимо только низкореповым этот мотиватор отображается

Comment: @vp_arth, включено право "Убрать рекламу"?

Comment: @Other, хм, так и есть. Баннеры справа тем не менее присутствуют.

Comment: Этот баннер вообще исчезает, когда достаточно репутации наберёшь. Остаётся только тот, что сбоку.

Comment: У меня его вообще нет. =\

Comment: @Suvitruf Задал вопрос про рекламу https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7320/220571