# Зачем нам реклама ruSO, если мы и так здесь?

Tags: предложение, дизайн, stackoverflow, реклама

### Сама проблема

Так выглядит наш сайт во вкладке инкогнито или когда у вас менее 200 репутации.
Рекламный баннер и по центру, и сбоку, что занимает очень много места:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но боковой баннер всегда есть, сколько бы репутации у вас не было.

### Можно ли обойтись без рекламы?

Уверен, что можно. Другие локализованные сообщества [ptSO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com) и [esSO](https://es.stackoverflow.com) прекрасно живут без неё, а на [jaSO](https://ja.stackoverflow.com) только реклама Microsoft (я хотя бы понимаю её смысл) без бокового баннера. Может, удалим рекламу, пока в ней не будет хоть какого-то смысла?

### Предыстория

Идея возника после комментариев ([Как вам идея перенести баннер stack overflow под ответы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7275/#comment29619_7275)) к [посту](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7275/220571), где довольно новый участник спрашивал про перемещение баннера, так как бы не уверен, можно ли вообще требовать удаление рекламы. Но в комментариях появлилось непонимание необходиомости данной рекламы

> Зачем вообще этот баннер, если я уже на SO =/
>
> Я понимаю, если бы я зашёл на en SO, а там бы была реклама ru SO, т.к. у меня IP Российский. Но на ru SO в этом банере нет смысла вообще

### Откуда у нас эта реклама?

Баннер возник как [инициатива](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2539/220571) для приобщения новичков задать свой первый вопрос. Прекрасная задумка с важной оговоркой

> В будущем мы планируем показывать их только неавторизованным пользователям, дабы уменьшить информационный шум постоянным участникам сообщества.

А этого по сути нет. У нас эта же реклама показывается всем: неважно анонимус вы или у вас уже триллионы заданных вопросов. Поэтому получается что с теми, у кого более одного вопроса, эта реклама остаётся навсегда и ситуация слегка исправляется когда пользователь достигает 200 репутации и исчезает верхний баннер.

### Возможные положительные эффекты от рекламы

Тут требуется статистика, которой у меня нет и которую я не знаю как получить. Возможно, от рекламы есть большой приток новичков и новых вопросов. Но наше сообщество занимает неплохие места в рейтингах StackExchange относительно других сообществ:

- [3е по кол-ву вопросов в день](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday)
- [6-е по кол-ву вопросов](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions)
- [6-е по кол-ву ответов](https://stackexchange.com/sites#answers)
- [8-е по трафику](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic)
- [20-е по кол-ву пользователей](https://stackexchange.com/sites#users)

При этом нам чуть больше 3х лет. Все сообщества, которые нас опережают существуют не меньше 7ми лет и являются англоязычными! По всем этим показателем мы являемся успешнейшим локализованным обществом Stack Overflow. Вполне возможно, что в этом сыграла большую роль данная реклама. Пока нет статистики это будет сложно опровергнуть или подвердить.

### Так что же делать с рекламой?

Если успех данного сообщества обусловен именно такого рода рекламой, то другим сообществам также надо перенимать такой опыт, так как я такого не видел нигде в сети StackExchange, чтобы рекламировалось само задавание вопросов. Ведь очевидна проблема того, что все сообщества кроме enSO довольно непопулярны. enSO выглядит огромным мегаполисом, а остальные сообщества выглядят деревнями на его фоне, где все друг друга знают и активных участников крайне мало. Если это действительно приводит активных участников, то это должно быть реализовано везде. **Но такая реклама должна быть только для неавторизованных пользоватей или новичков, у которых нет никакой активности на сайте, иначе она просто бессмысленна: занимает много места и раздражает.**

Если эта реклама никак или почти не повлияла на успех, то тут, очевидно, что её надо убирать.

Если реклама хоть как-то повлияла на успех и при этом технически очень проблемно реализовать показ в зависимости от авторизованности/пользователя, то можем
провести эксперимент: попробовать убрать центральный или боковой баннер и посмотреть как это скажется на активности новых участников.

Comment: так боковой баннер не реклама, а призыв задавать еще :-)

Comment: @Grundy Это именно реклама (на enSO там бывают разные штуки) и без него, уверен, можно обойтись. Гляньте любой вопрос на [ptSO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com) и [esSO](https://es.stackoverflow.com) — чисто контент, без призывов. Разве так хуже?

Comment: Согласен с тем, что боковой баннер нужно убирать, и как на esSO, выкладывать туда вакансии, это больший стимул к развитию. (Когда видишь зарплаты по 90 тысяч долларов в месяц).

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов на западе принято указывать зп в год и до налогов. 90 тыс в год минус налоги - это примерно 4-4.5 в месяц, вполне достижимая зп для лид дева даже в наших краях.

Comment: @PashaPash да это конечно, бесспорно я обратного не говорил. Просто говорю, что вакансии с указанием зарплаты, как по мне, стимулируют людей больше, чем очень креативные баннеры.

Comment: Таки да, у меня включен адблок на этом сайте только из-за этого баннера, ибо задолбал