# Задавать вопросы стыдно?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Увидел сегодня вот такую плашку.

> [image: плашка]

Из фразы

> Не стыдись спросить - не знать ещё постыднее!

Делается вывод, что спрашивать или не знать чего-то является постыдным. По мне, это в корне некорректно, и такому не место на нашем сайте.

Хотелось бы узнать мнение других участников и попросить администрацию выпилить это, если моё предложение имеет смысл не только для меня, но и для сообщества.

**UPD.**

Походу я сформулировал свой вопрос не совсем верно, потому попробую это исправить.

### Зачем вообще это всё

Я бы даже не увидел этот текст, если бы не открыл сайт в инкогнито, когда тестил разные цветовые режимы. Мне фраза резанула глаза. Я подумал: "А что если спросить мнение сообщества на эту тему, ведь эту фразу можно сделать лучше." Всё, больше мыслей у меня не возникло. Никаких споров я не предвидел, никакой политики или какого мракобесия я не планировал. Я решил, что если сделать доброе дело и зарепортить пусть такую маленькую вещь, то можно сделать наш сайт ну чууууть чуть получше (в моем понимании конечно).

### Что я имею ввиду

Все, что я имел ввиду - это то, что посыл в фразе `Не стыдись спросить - не знать ещё постыднее!` - не соответсвует нашим ценностям.

По сути меня интересуют два вопроса:

1. Считаете ли вы, что эта цитата является верной для вас или для нашего сообщества? (ответ Да/Нет меня устроит, доп комментарии приветсвуются)
2. Считаете ли вы, что можно эту цитату перефразировать/улучшить или вы предпочитаете оставить её как есть? (Да/Нет сгодится, доп комментарии приветвуются)

### Что я точно не имею ввиду

1. Я не был обижен или оскорблен этим текстом, я не ищу обиженных или оскорбленных этим текстом, я не ищу тех, которых этот текст никак не задевает.
2. Я не ищу какие-либо очевидные или глубокие мысли на тему как надо жить. Если у вас есть мудрость, которой вы хотите поделиться, я только рад почитать, просто имейте ввиду, что это не относится к вопросу.
3. Я также не хочу ничего сказать по поводу автора текста, мы тут обсуждаем только сам текст.
4. Я также не спрашиваю, что вам ещё, кроме этого текста, не нравится в нашей повседневной жизни. Вы можете этим поделиться, я с удовольствием почитаю, просто вопросу это никак не поможет.
5. Тут начинают писать про какие то комплексы, обиды, оскобления и прочее. Это конечно наши реалии, но это не относится к вопросу. Если говорить про меня лично, то я работал на Челябинском Трубопрокатном заводе, меня обидеть очень сложно и фраза из рекламы интернете это не то, что может повлиять на мое психологическое состояние.

Я надеюсь, что теперь вопрос стал более понятным. Мои извинения если изначальный текст ввел вас в заблуждение.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119842/discussion-on-question-by-tym32167---).

Answer (score 18):

В целом эта фраза построена так, что воспринимается больше как "восточная мудрость" чем как прямой намек-оскорбление. То есть, если уж ты стыдишься спросить, то ты фокусируешься на на том. Более корректный вариант: "Не стыдись спросить, а стыдись не знать".

Я бы и не обратил никогда на нее внимание. А если бы обратил, то вывод бы сделал что она адресована не мне (я то ведь не стыжусь).

Answer (score 15):

Формулировка цитаты, наверное, не совсем удачна. В моём понимании должно предполагаться что-то вроде "Не стыдно не знать, стыдно - не пытаться узнать". А вот как узнать - это уже следующее дело. Кто-то может узнать сам путём прочтения документации, книг, экспериментов или ответов других участников. А кому-то проще сформулировать свой вопрос сообществу и получить ответ для восполнения нехватки знаний в определённой теме.

Здесь ненароком вспоминаются участники-долгожители с множеством ответов, но при этом не задавшие ни единого вопроса на сайте. Вероятно, такие люди как раз относятся к первой категории, которым проще (или интереснее?) найти ответ самостоятельно, нежели воспользоваться помощью коллег по цеху. А может им действительно стыдно спросить, т.к. это покажет их "слабость"? Трудно сказать. Наверное, у каждого на это свои причины. В ситуацию, что у них не возникает вопросов поверить же просто невозможно.

В целом баннер призывает просто быть активнее на сайте, дабы наполнять его контентом. Сайт без полезных ответов был бы ущербен, но полезные (да и любые другие) ответы не появятся, если не будет подходящих вопросов.

Хотя в какой-то мере упоминание стыда в цитате, как чего-то постыдного (масло масленное), негативного, не подходящего для достойного человека, может быть воспринято и так: "Не будь тряпкой - задай вопрос". Достаточно провокационно, как мне кажется.

При этом, насколько я знаю, все существующие на данный момент баннеры для продвижения ruSO были созданы достаточно давно и не проходили какой-то профессиональной проверки, обсуждались (и утверждались) небольшим составом участников. Все эти баннеры стоило бы признать устаревшими и выпилить с сайта. Но, видимо, не хочется оставлять на этом месте пустоту, а бюджета на новые не заложено. Поэтому они и мозолят глаз.

Связанный вопрос по баннерам: [Зачем нам реклама ruSO, если мы и так здесь?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7320/176217) К сожалению, без ответа уже почти 3 года.

P.S. Попробую привлечь внимание к ситуации ещё и таким способом:

> [image: Жалоба на рекламу]

Указал в отзыве ссылку на текущее обсуждение.

Comment: Так можно перефразировать же. У меня претензия к этой фразе чисто логическая. Из нее получается, что есть ты пришёл сюда задать вопрос - тебе уже должно быть стыдно. А если вопрос не задашь - должно быть стыдно вдвойне. Ну это неправильно же, разве нет?

Comment: @tym32167 перефразировать это никто не будет. Тем более, что интерпретации могут быть разные. Например, для тех, кто стыдится задать вопрос - слоган актуален. Для тех, кто не стыдится - нет.

Comment: @tym32167, фраза авторская и подписана. Полагаю, если хочется её перефразировать, стоит это обсудить с её автором. Просто так править чужие баннеры - так себе идея.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, какие ещё бюджеты, если вот [тема на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2539/178988) и никаких новых фраз с 2016 года никто и не предлагал?

Comment: @Qwertiy кто ж спорит. Я даже заморочился и вопрос задал перед тем, чтобы что то предлагать вообще.

Comment: @Qwertiy бюджеты SO. Понятно, что всё это мои предположения - у меня нет информации о том, на что и сколько распределено ресурсов компании. Но очевидно, что в данном случае требуется вмешательство сотрудника компании, а значит этот труд будет так или иначе оплачен. Если КМ отписался в соседнем ответе, то, вероятно, что ресурсы на это всё же могут найтись. Но моё имхо, что дальше разговоров дело на дойдёт в ближайшей перспективе. Баннер так и останется висеть как был.

Answer (score 4):

Соглашусь с @tym32167. Вот его комментарий:

> цитата Сократа Не стыдно чего-нибудь не знать, но стыдно не хотеть
> учиться. - тоже не супер идеально, но посыл уже совершенно другой.

Всё верно, Сократ, а он был великий философ и Гений, считал, что чего-то не знать совсем не стыдно. А на плашке говорится - стыдно. То есть всё наоборот. Более того, нет логики в написанном на плашке, она, как мне кажется, отсутствует напрочь.

Вот приведу пример. Я создаю сайты уже больше двадцати лет. Были как очень простые работы, так и сверх сложные. И при всем этом, я даже самый простой язык - CSS знаю не в совершенстве. И мне совсем не стыдно задавать вопросы. А плашка говорит мне - "Не стыдись спросить". Но мне нисколько не стыдно спросить. А плашка мне вдогонку - "Не знать еще постыднее". Что-то я не совсем понимаю. Во-первых, если мне задать вопрос не стыдно, то как "постыднее" мне должно быть чего-то не знать? Где логика в этом? Во-вторых, почему мне собственно должно быть стыдно чего-то не знать? Какая глупость. Нет на земле такого человека, нет специалиста даже в какой-либо узкой отрасли, который бы всё знал по своей специальности.

Есть у нас, кстати, замечательные цитаты из жизни, например: "Учиться, учиться и учиться", или "Век живи, век учись". Вот они нас призывают - учиться, спрашивать и знать. А плашка пытается тыкнуть носом об "облико морале". Призыв и упрек - вот разница.

Один момент, который самый важный - если мне эта плашка до фени, то кого-то она может задеть и заставить себя почувствовать не совсем уютно. Мы не должны тыкать носом, мы должны призывать, при этом уважая чувства собственного достоинства каждого пользователя нашего сообщества! Нас всегда учили - прежде чем что-то сказать, сначала подумай. А тем более, как оказалось, это касается еще и лозунгов, прежде чем их вешать на стену.

Всем добра!

Comment: Мне кажется, вы к обсуждению уместности текста на плашке добавили обсуждение личности автора текста.

Comment: @VladD, ну да, противоречить не буду, перебрал малость. Ответ отредактировал. Приношу свои извинения. Однако, скрывать не буду, что большой любви к автору написанного на этой плашке не испытываю, так как прочитав такое "высказывание", у меня создается впечатление, что человек, сказавший так, смотрит на окружающих с высоты птичьего полета.

Comment: "Век живи, век учись!" - вот оно! Нет?! И ни какого негатива, и всем известное изречение, и мотивирует учиться не взирая на возраст.

Comment: @XelaNimed, именно да. Плюс ко всему еще - никакой навязчивости, а только призыв, и никакого давления на личность, а касается всех. Вот такое и принимается, а не отторгается. И не поспоришь, потому что оснований нет.

Answer (score 2):

Для меня этот банер звучит агрессивно, и вот почему мне так кажется. Я не думаю, что один человек имеет право стыдить другого за что-то, в чём тот человек свободен. Спросить или нет, знать или нет, хотеть учиться или нет — это личный выбор каждого, и, стыдя за него, мы проявляем насилие, навязываем свои нормы и ценности.

Стыдно может быть за что-то, приносящее вред другим. Например, стыдно не знать что-то, если ты должен знать, мог узнать и твоё незнание может навредить. Это и к программистам относится, потому что ценой их халтуры могут быть человеческие время, деньги, чувства и даже жизнь. Но это довольно сложное сочетание условий для простого банера. Нужна чуткость и талант сформулировать этот так, чтобы человеку не казалось, что его кто-то к чему-то принуждает или осуждает без права. А в такой упрощённой и при этом категоричной форме, увы, банер слишком часто будет промахиваться и бить по разным больным точкам. Вместо побуждения к первому шагу на сайте, он может вызвать раздражение и отторжение.

Comment: `потому что ценой их халтуры могут быть человеческие время, деньги, чувства и даже жизнь` — ну, не только халтуры, мне вот что-то кажется, что от чего-то написаного очень профессионально и без халтуры этот вред тоже может быть. Вредоносное ПО никто не отменял. Но я не могу сказать, что стыдно знать, как оно производится, используется и т.д. в теории. Это полезно. Т.е. знать что-то лишним не бывает ИМХО.

Answer (score 0):

Этот баннер, как и другие, созданы нами вместе как часть инициативы  [Поможем коллегам сделать первый шаг к профессиональному росту](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/) более пяти лет назад.

#### Страх быть отвергнутым группой

Считается, что любой человек испытывает два страха на бессознательном уровне:

1. Страх остаться без пищи.
2. Страх быть отвергнутым группой.

В контексте нашего сообщества страх быть отвергнутым группой играет ключевую роль. Когда мы задаем вопрос, мы ставим себя в уязвимое положение. Внутри нас срабатывают  защитные механизмы и мы расцениваем подобное как потенциальную угрозу выживания. Задавать вопросы на общедоступном сайте в интернете — огромный стресс. Мы все — разные и по разному воспринимаем стресс от публичных выступлений перед незнакомыми людьми. Для кого-то этот стресс ассоциируется со стыдом, для кого–то с неловкостью, для третьих это будет что–то другое. Как результат, как мне кажется, слоган может выражать чувства части аудитории. Я бы не стал убирать его из ротации.

#### Слоган должен привлекать внимание

> Не стыдись спросить - не знать ещё постыднее!

Фраза привлекает внимание, что, наверное, и требуется от слогана на баннере :)

#### Пришло время создать новые баннеры?

Слоганы на баннерах — это цитаты конкретных участников. Если мы хотим внести изменения, на мой взгляд, можно создать новые баннеры в дополнение или на замену старых. Что думаете?

Comment: `Фраза привлекает внимание` - ну и что? Знаете, у нас в городе одно время висел рекламный баннер, на котором была изображена красивая девушка в таком немного эротичном исполнении, и на баннере была следующая надпись: "_Мой сосед мне дал... взаймы_".  Да, такая реклама конечно привлекает внимание, и кому-то она нравится. Но не учли одного - аудитория то разная. Придумать красивый и главное - правильный слоган - это искусство.

Comment: Это демагогия. Если наша мотивация - это выразить что чувствует какая то неведомая часть юзеров, то слоган должен быть `Лень решать домашку - скинь её вопросом!`. Если мы хотим привлечь внимание к баннеру, надо туда повесить обнаженную женщину. Мое мнение - баннер должен мотивировать посетителей писать вопросы/ответы, а указание ему, что он стыдится или должен стыдиться может оттолкнуть.

Comment: Но мой вопрос даже не столько о том, как баннер воспримут посетители, как о том, как этот баннер отражает вобще наше сообщество. Должны ли мы встречать новичков такой фразой - коррелирует ли это с нашими ценностями?

Comment: @tym32167, ну вроде наши ценности в том, что вопросы по умолчанию хорошие, так что фраза, призывающая не бояться спрашивать вполне с ними коррелирует.

Comment: @Qwertiy фраза говорит, что спрашивать должно быть стыдно, но это ок, ведь не знать ещё постыдней. Чет я тут не вижу про "не бояться спрашивать" ничего.

Comment: @tym32167, а мне кажется фраза о том, что спрашивать как раз **не стыдно**, что  должно быть **стыдно не спрашивать** (что в нашей реальности входит в противоречие с закрытием плохих вопросов).

Comment: @Nicolas, Может какую голосовалку за новые баннеры запустить?

Comment: @tym32167 Отличная идея, спасибо! Я добавил эту тему в список для обсуждения с коллегами. Посмотрим, что они скажут!